# Magento 2 - Really Bad Performance in Docker

Tags: magento2, performance, static-content-deploy, deployment, docker

we are using Docker on macOS for development and deployment and have massive performance problems especially in deployment.

Our deployment does a full project build with:

- git clone
- composer install
- bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US de_DE --exclude-theme Magento/blank --exclude-theme Magento/luma --force (take 3000 secs!!!!)
- bin/magento setup:di:compile (take ~1000secs!!!!)

Does anyone know why these processes took that much time?

Update 08.2018

Now we are using docker-sync which "works", but adds an extra layer of complexity to all our M" projects which I want to avoid.

It's such a shame for Magento that it does not optimize for development workflow. All other projects like Laravel, Symfony, TYPO3, Drupal etc works like a charm but M2 sucks in performance caused by the count of files which needs to be read in a request lifecycle.

You can read more about this problem in this post:
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs-caching/

Answer (score 2):

Shared Filesystem for Docker on MacOS is nightmarishly slow.

I will suggest:

- Do not use a shared filesystem  at all (and use PhpStorm Deploymechanism or http://docker-sync.io/)
- Share only your code  (using composer base instalation and share   app/code/YourVendor or app/theme/*/YourVendor)

Comment: currently we are using docker-sync, but it's such an extra part of complexity, which I want to kick off. The crux is each other php project like M1, Laravel, TYPO3 etc. works like a charm and only M2 sucks with all its files...

Comment: Hi @KAndy, bambamboole It will be very appreciating if you can help me in a related issue. I found very little help for docker+Git and MacOS issues https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/275149/m2-how-can-we-use-same-code-base-among-all-team-members-via-git

Answer (score 0):

Try this for superp performance on docker for magento. Tested on macOS for magento2.3.5
https://arunkp123.github.io/magdock/